# mysql LOAD DATA INFILE OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '(' AND ')'

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have some problems with the LOAD DATA INFILE practically the path of the text file is unable to load on mysql.

I tried with many combinations but I can't, could you kindly help me

I advance a question, with the LOAD DATA INFILE method this loads all the records or just the first coincidence? in my sample more are expected ADOP ADEP ADUSF records.

the text block start with ADSTART and ends before the next one ADSTART, characters such as £ or $ are also expected on values records.

Is the approach I should follow this LOAD DATA INFILE or integrate php or python for data extraction?

details below

```
ADSTART ADID(APP£AAA£000) STATUS(A) TYPE(A)
ADOP WSID(RZGY) OPNO(001) JOBN()
ADSTART ADID(APP£001) STATUS(A)
ADOP WSID(NULL) OPNO(001) JOBN()
ADOP WSID(ENG1) OPNO(005) JOBN(JAAABR14)
ADDEP PREADID() PREWSID(NULL) PREOPNO(001)
   DESCR() PR£INT(A)
ADUSF UFNAME(JBLIB) UFVALUE(000)
ADUSF UFNAME(SUBJOBUSER) UFVALUE(SU06)
ADOP WSID(ENG1) OPNO(010) JOBN(JBBBBR15)
ADDEP PREADID() PREWSID(NULL) PREOPNO(001)
ADUSF UFNAME(JBLIB) UFVALUE(000)
ADUSF UFNAME(SUBJOBUSER) UFVALUE(SU06)
ADDEP PREADID() PREWSID(ENG1) PREOPNO(005)
   DESCR() PR£INT(A)
ADSTART ADID(APP£BBB£002) STATUS(P)
ADOP WSID(NULL) OPNO(001) JOBN()
ADOP WSID(ENG1) OPNO(005) JOBN(JCCCBR14)
ADDEP PREADID() PREWSID(NULL) PREOPNO(001)
ADDEP PREADID(APP£001) PREWSID(ENG1) PREOPNO(005)
   DESCR() PR£INT(A)
ADUSF UFNAME(JBLIB) UFVALUE(000)
ADUSF UFNAME(SUBJOBUSER) UFVALUE(SU06)
```

def table appjs for test

```
CREATE TABLE appjs (
    adid VARCHAR(100),
    status VARCHAR(100),
    wsid VARCHAR(100),
    opno VARCHAR(100),
    jobn VARCHAR(100),
    preadid VARCHAR(100),
    prewsid VARCHAR(100),
    preopno VARCHAR(100),
    ufname VARCHAR(100),
    ufvalue VARCHAR(100)
);
```

i'm use client DBeaver 23.2.5

instruction: (10.4.20-MariaDB)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'adid_full.txt'
INTO TABLE appjs
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '(' AND ')'
LINES TERMINATED BY 'ADSTART'
(adid, status, wsid, opno, jobn, preadid, prewsid, preopno, ufname, ufvalue);
```

error:

```
Errore SQL [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND ')'
LINES TERMINATED BY 'ADSTART'
(adid, status, wsid, opno, jobn, prea...' at line 3
```

Sorry if I didn't enter the result I needed:

follow sample data desired final

select *
from appjs
order by adid;

```
adid       |status|wsid|opno|jobn    |preadid|prewsid|preopno|ufname    |ufvalue|
-----------+------+----+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+----------+-------+
APP£001    |A     |    |001 |        |       |       |       |          |       |
APP£001    |A     |ENG1|005 |JAAABR14|       |NULL   |001    |JBLIB     |000    |
APP£001    |A     |ENG1|010 |JBBBBR15|       |NULL   |001    |JBLIB     |000    |
APP£001    |A     |ENG1|010 |JBBBBR15|       |NULL   |001    |SUBJOBUSER|SU06   |
APP£001    |A     |ENG1|010 |JBBBBR15|       |ENG1   |005    |          |       |
APP£001    |A     |NULL|001 |        |       |       |       |          |       |
APP£BBB£002|P     |NULL|001 |        |       |       |       |          |       |
APP£BBB£002|P     |ENG1|005 |JCCCBR14|       |NULL   |001    |          |       |
APP£BBB£002|P     |ENG1|005 |JCCCBR14|APP£001|ENG1   |005    |JBLIB     |000    |
APP£BBB£002|P     |ENG1|005 |JCCCBR14|APP£001|ENG1   |005    |SUBJOBUSER|SU06   |
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show desired final data state for shown sample data. Anycase - in such complex input format use input preprocessing. Or even LOAD_FILE.

Comment: this looks more complex than load data will support, and doing it in code probably makes sense.  but you should show the rows you want generated from your sample data; I have several questions

Comment: `LOAD DATA` expects data in regular rows with a consistent number of fields per row. It simply isn't built for data in this format with variable numbers of fields and multiple duplicate fields in each block. Your attempt to extend the syntax with `AND` is just wrong. You will need a more sophisticated parser written in some language other than SQL.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't enter the result I needed:, i'm update post. thanks. @easleyfixed mysql workbench accept only csv and json files, my file it's a text plain file. thanks for answer.

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular ysth yes. is a format with variable numbers of fields and multiple duplicate fields in each block. I did it like this because I had already done it with an xml file, I thought it was almost the same. therefore another type of approach is needed, perhaps with php or python to extract data? thanks.

Comment: Your original data is cumulative. LOAD DATA cannot import such file. Recommendation: load this file into temptable, one row per line, then iterate over this file saving previous lines values into UDV or clear them (depends of line content mark) and save this data into working table.

Comment: thanks for the answers, it's true the data is all variable and repeats itself in a different and cumulative way. I'll try to do something with php or python as i'm self-taught.